# creating a new workflow by using the existing workflow - Modifications are not Saved

Tags: workflow, aem

Am creating a new workflow by using the existing workflow ( i.e. By copying the existing workflow under  `/etc/workflow/models/`).
But when I do this the newly created workflow is not saved for any future modifications. Observed that the newly created workflow is having a version as `jcr:rootVersion` and also the model is having the `jcr:predecessors` property of Type `Reference[]`  is having a value as shown in below screenshot. Can’t we reuse the existing models in the way which I am trying ? or how to restrict the value ?

[image: Workflow]

[image: screenshot]

[image: workflow]
[image: New Workflow Node]
[image: Existing Workflow Node]

Comment: have you tried to copy the whole page? the flow node is also part of the workflow defition.

Comment: The node name issue got resolved by deleting the ".../sample-workflow123/jcr:content/model" model node. And it is re-created when i hit save for the next time.
But problem here is for further modifactions the version number is not changing from 1.0 to next levels (i.e 1.1, 1.2, etc)

Answer (score 0):

modification in jcr are not the best supported ones. If you want to create a new workflow use the workflow console, create a new workflow and add the steps you want to reuse. Also you can reuse workflow by adding them to a container step. I'm not sure which one do you want to use, if you want to expand an already existing workflow then go on and create a new one and add the pages, if you just want to call an already existing workflow than use the container step. Take care, the container step will generate a new workflow instance from the sub workflow and the main workflow won't wait for the sub-workflow to finish.